# Erro ao encontrar modulo NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou seguindo um livro de `NodeJS` e está dando o seguinte erro:

```
Error: Cannot find module './app/routes/home'
```

Já revisei várias vezes e não encontrei nada errado, aqui está o código:

Express.js

```
// config/express.js
var express = require('express');
var home = require('./app/routes/home');
module.exports = function () {
    var app = express();
    // variável de ambiente
    app.set('port', 3000);

    // middleware responsavel por tornar acessivel tudo dentro da pasta public, recebe como parametro a pasta public
    app.use(express.static('./public'));
    //No Express, template engines são confiurados em variáveis de ambiente
    //view engine utilizada é ejs.  
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    //definimos o diretório onde fiarão nossas views
    app.set('views', './app/views');
    home(app);

    return app;
};
```

Route:

```
// app/routes/home.js

var controller = require('./app/controller/home');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/index', controller.index);
    app.get('/', controller.index);

}
```

Controller:

```
// app/controllers/home.js
module.exports = function () {
    var controller = {};
    controller.index = function (req, res) {
        res.render('index', { nome: 'Express' });
    };
    return controller;
}
```

E por ultimo o server.js

```
// server.js
var http = require('http');
var app = require('./config/express')();
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express Server escutando na porta ' +
        app.get('port'));
});
```

Aonde posso estar errando?

Estrutura dos diretórios[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]:

Comment: Será que pode ser algum problema no `EJS` ?

Comment: `var controller = require('./app/controller/home');` não falta um `s` em `controller`?

Comment: Também achei de inicio, porém no livro está sem o `s` mas mesmo assim coloquei e o erro persiste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu costumo usar `console.log(__dirname);` quando não tenho a certeza de que diretoria o ficheiro está.

No teu caso tens um erro no nome da diretoria `controllers` ou no caminho que apontas `var controller = require('./app/controller/home');`. Repara no `s` que os diferencia.

Corrigindo isso usa `../` para descer um nivel de diretório em relação àquele em que o ficheiro está. Respetivamente:

```
var home = require('../app/routes/home');
```

e

```
var controller = require('../controller/home');
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que foi descido somente um nível de diretório e o diretório pretendido esta dois níveis abaixo.
ao invés de:

```
../app/controllers/home
```

Usar:

```
../../app/controllers/home
```